# submit form if don't have error

Tags: ajax

i am using ajax for send active form by this function

```
      public    function Link()
    {
        $id=$this->params['id'];
        $url=$this->params['url'];
        $dviId=$this->params['divId'];
 $url=Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl($url);
           $js2="$('#".$id."').on('click', function() { $.ajax({url: '".$url."',type: 'POST',success : function(res){ $('#".$dviId."').html(res);}});});";


        $view = $this->getView();
        AjaxAsset::register($view);

        if ($js2 !== '') {
            $view->registerJs($js2);
        }
        return ;
    }
```

And want to show error if any happened else send form

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin in jquery to do client side validation if you are using javascript and want to do initial validation of the form.

```
http://jqueryvalidation.org/
```

Also you can use "required" attribute in your text tags to do some intial checks. More can be found here:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: sorry but i use yii and yii validation

Answer (score 1):

You can also set [enableAjaxValidation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#$enableAjaxValidation-detail) to `true` in your form.

There is an [example](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#ajax-validation) in the docs about that (see the controller part).

Answer (score 1):

```
        public   function Link()

    {
        $id=$this->params['id'];
        $url=$this->params['url'];
        $dviId=$this->params['divId'];
        if(isset($this->params['confirm'])) {
            $confirm = "if(confirm('".$this->params['confirm']."')){";
            $endConfirm = "}";
        }
        else
        {
            $confirm = "";
            $endConfirm = "";
        }
 $url=Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl($url);
        $js2="$('#".$id."').on('click', function() {".$confirm."$.ajax({url: '".$url."',type: 'POST',beforeSend: function(){ $('body').addClass('wait');},complete: function(){ $('body').removeClass('wait');},success : function(res){ $('#".$dviId."').html(res);}});".$endConfirm."});";

        $view = $this->getView();
        AjaxAsset::register($view);

        if ($js2 !== '') {
            $view->registerJs($js2);
        }
        return ;
    }
```